# Am I supposed to worry about npm package vulnerabilities?

Tags: node.js, npm

[image: "npm install" results]

The picture shows it all, am I supossed to worry about this? Is it normal? And if it can lead to problems how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After each `npm install` npm runs `npm audit`, which can lead to output like in your image.

Generally speaking, it depends on the environment the "vulnerable" code will run. Is it a dev dependency, that only runs on the developer's local machine.. Or is it shipped to production?

Dan Abramov covered the topic sarcastically here: overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design